# Can we do navigation to standard record create page in wire service?

Tags: lightning-web-components, aura, new

I want to pre-populate one of the Country field value from User object to Account's Visiting Country when I try to create an Account. I have overridden Standard New Button on Account with Aura Component which calls LWC and in LWC I have added wire service that navigates to Standard record create page.

Below is the code that I have used:

**Aura Comp:**

```
<aura:component
    implements="lightning:actionOverride,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,force:hasSObjectName,lightning:hasPageReference"
    access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="selectedRecordId" type="Id" />
    <!--Declare Handler-->
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <c:navToNewAccRecordWithDefaults recordTypeId="{!v.selectedRecordId}"/>
</aura:component>
```

**Aura JS:**

```
({
    doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
        //get record type Id
        let recordTypeId = component.get("v.pageReference").state.recordTypeId;
        console.log('Aura Rec ID:'+recordTypeId);
        component.set("v.selectedRecordId", recordTypeId);
    }
})
```

**LWC JS:**

```
import { LightningElement,wire,api } from 'lwc';
import USER_ID from '@salesforce/user/Id';
import { getRecord} from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import USERCOUNTRY_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/User.Account_Country__c';
import { encodeDefaultFieldValues } from 'lightning/pageReferenceUtils';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
const FIELDS = [USERCOUNTRY_FIELD];
export default class NavToNewAccRecordWithDefaults extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    userDefaultCountry;
    error;
    @api recordTypeId;
    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: USER_ID, fields: FIELDS}) 
    userDetails({error, data}) {
        if (data) {
            this.userDefaultCountry = data.fields.Default_Account_Country__c.value;
            console.log('userDefaultCountry:'+this.userDefaultCountry);
            //if(this.userDefaultCountry !== undefined && this.userDefaultCountry !== null){
                this.navigateToNewAccountWithDefaults();
            //}
        } else if (error) {
            console.log('error is:'+error);
            this.error = error ;
        }
    }

    navigateToNewAccountWithDefaults() {
        console.log('Calling navigateToNewContactWithDefaults....'+this.recordTypeId)
        const defaultValues = encodeDefaultFieldValues({
           RecordTypeId: this.recordTypeId,
           BillingCountryCode: this.userDefaultCountry
        });

        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__objectPage',
            attributes: {
                objectApiName: 'Account',
                actionName: 'new'
            },
            state: {
                defaultFieldValues: defaultValues // set defaults as a nav parameter
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In console log , I am getting Record Type Id as well as Country but I am getting blank screen instead of Record Create form. It's not launching Standard Account Record create form.

What am I missing here?

Is it possible to override Std. new button and add Navigation event that navigates to record create page with pre-populated values?

**Update :** After Adding additional parameters in State , it works in desktop application but if In Mobile application, after clicking on Cancel button, its not navigating back.

How to fix navigation in Mobile app?

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__objectPage',
            attributes: {
                objectApiName: 'Account',
                actionName: 'new'
            },
            state: {
                count: '1',
                nooverride: '1',
                useRecordTypeCheck : '1',
                defaultFieldValues: defaultValues, 
                navigationLocation: 'LIST_VIEW',
                backgroundContext: '/lightning/o/Account/list?filterName=Recent',
                recordTypeId: this.recordTypeId,
            }
        })
```

Comment: Any errors on your browser's Developer Console (typically F12)? What does the URL look like? Any further details you can share about this?

Comment: @sfdcfox There was no such error observed in browser's console. I even put debug after navigation logic and was able to see the same on console. Without any exceptions, it's difficult to understand what's the issue here?

Comment: @sfdcfox When I override new button then URL looks like: https://my.lightning.force.com/lightning/o/Account/new?count=2 and for Standard New button with no override URL display like this   https://my.lightning.force.com/lightning/o/Account/new?count=1&nooverride=1&useRecordTypeCheck=1&navigationLocation=LIST_VIEW&uid=123456&backgroundContext=%2Flightning%2Fo%2FAccount%2Flist%3FfilterName%3DRecent&recordTypeId=0121o0000087658ret

Comment: Hi, @sfdcfox  I am able to launch Std. New Record Page.Please check Update in Question. In Mobile application when I try to click on cancel button, it's not navigating back and the screen stuck, is there a way to listen standard cancel / save button event in LWC?

Comment: @sfdcfox I have posted new question https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/369089/is-there-a-way-to-listen-standard-cancel-save-button-event-of-standard-record-fo