# Is there a way to Listen Standard Cancel/Save button event of Standard Record form in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, event, button

I am using NavigationMixin to navigate to Record create page as below:

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__objectPage',
            attributes: {
                objectApiName: 'Account',
                actionName: 'new'
            }
})
```

It display Standard Record Create Form with Save,Cancel and Save&New in Desktop application and In Mobile application, it shows Save & cancel button.

In Mobile application, When I click on Cancel button, I am not able to navigate back to List View or If I try to create Record, it does not navigate to Record detail page.

I have updated NavigationMixin as below which works in Desktop application but does not work in Mobile application:

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__objectPage',
            attributes: {
                objectApiName: 'Account',
                actionName: 'new'
            },
            state: {
                count: '1',
                nooverride: '1',
                navigationLocation: 'LIST_VIEW',
                backgroundContext: '/lightning/o/Account/list?filterName=Recent',
                recordTypeId: this.recordTypeId,
            }
        })
```

Can someone please tell me what is wrong in above code?
Is there a way to listen Standard Cancel / Save button onclick event in LWC?

Comment: You found any solution for this?

Comment: @MuzammilBajaria No. Seems there's navigation issue in mobile application. Tried with VF also same result.